# lombok @AllArgsConstructor constructor

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, lombok

I am new to lombok. I have defined the below model using lombok. However when I try to create a object of the model with parameters, it gives an error stating `Paramterized connstructor is not defined`. From what I have read, `@AllArgsConstructor`, `@NoArgsConstructor` should create both a paramterized and default constructor.
I am able to access my parameters so I am sure lombok is setup correctly.

Am I missing something here?

```
 @Data
 @AllArgsConstructor
 @NoArgsConstructor
 public class SomeObjectModel {

   @JsonProperty("task")
   State task;

   @JsonProperty("time")
   long time;

   @JsonProperty("bool")
   boolean bool;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: What tool generates the error message? Can you also fix the typo's in the error message, unless that's the actual erro message you see?

Comment: I think the problem is mixin `@Data` and `@AllArgsConstructors` annotations. As we know `@Data` also generates constructor based on final fields. Since  you have no final fields there is no parameter constructor. Do you have "delombok" feature in eclipse plugin? If yse, then please use it and paste to question delomboked code. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to install Lombok in your IDE (based on your post tags seems that you are using Eclipse)

Steps:

1. In your maven dependencies check your Lombok jar location (As alternative you can download the jar file directly from the [Lombok web site](https://projectlombok.org/download))
   [Lombok location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xea1T.png)
2. Close Eclipse
3. Open a command line where the Lombok jar file is located
4. Execute **java -jar lombok-[VERSION].jar** (An installation wizard will be opened)
   [Installation wizard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XFneG.png)
5. Out of the box the wizard will try to find your IDE installation, if the wizard doesn't find it, then you will have to provide the path
6. Click on "Install/Update" button
7. Close the installation wizard and open Eclipse
8. Update your maven project
   [Update project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BpoHU.png)

I hope it helps!!!